# java eclipse auto-formatting braces indentation

Tags: java, eclipse, autoformatting

My problem with eclipse's auto format is that it's taking this:

```
public List<JSON> getIdentityQualifiers(String identity)
        throws DatabaseException
{
     //....code
}
```

to this:

```
public List<JSON> getIdentityQualifiers(String identity)
        throws DatabaseException
        {
    //....code
        }
```

Obviously, I want to keep the previous formatting, but I can't find where to control this.

Comment: Uh... Just type "indent" in the preferences. There aren't many options there (one is Java Formatter that has a subsection on "braces position" when configuring the profiles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think basically it may have been my version of Eclipse or something obscure as this stopped happening a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Project -> Properties -> Java Code Style -> Formatter` and you will see the formatting options. There are a lot of different styles.

My company provides us with a custom XML which defines exactly how they want things formatted, which was created internally. Eclipse allows you to define your formatting exactly in this format. There will certainly be tutorials online if this is important to you. You may be able to write your own or find many examples in Eclipse marketplace and online.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of these things, and my team has setup a custom formatter. However, something has happened and it's now doing this and I'm hoping someone can give me a bit more detail of where I go to fix this. When I remove the throws statement, the method formats correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try like that , first select segment of code which one you want to indent for e.g

```
              if(true)
            {
                           System.out.println("INDENTED");
            }
```

select and type Ctrl + Shift + F.
After that you get.

```
               if (true) {
                System.out.println("INDENTED");
            }
```

For customization you can find from there  *Project --> Properties --> Java Code Style --> *